# preg_replace Ñ with correct character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace the value of Ñ in a preg_replace.
I have this code:

```
<?php
$name = 'AVENDAÑO, PAULVIC T.';
$match = preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/','N',$name);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($match);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Though variable $name holds AVENDAÑO, PAULVIC T. Still it displays AVENDAÃ‘O, PAULVIC T.

But when I try to use the code above it replaces all non-characters to N.

I know there's something wrong with my regex or does anyone knows any alternative to solve these problem regarding character formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str_replace instead.

```
<?php
$name = 'AVENDAÑO, PAULVIC T.';
$match = str_replace('Ñ','N',$name);

echo $match;
?>
```

Comment: Do you think there is still a way to display Ñ on screen correctly? Suppose that i want str_replace('Ñ','Ñ',$name);

Comment: If this is in a web page, check that the code page that is used is correct. UTF-8 is probably the one you want to use: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` should sort it out. If it's in a shell session, check the code page there too.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use `iconv` http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $name);
```

Comment: this results to AVENDA~NO, PAULVIC T.

Comment: Not quite sure what the first / second params should be, check the PHP documentation for better information, I used this functionality rarely, but it's the best to use, since you need to write a few hundred str_replace() for every special char :)